# replace old array with new array in string

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace

I have a var contains string and I have array with words from the string called oldWords and new array with the new words called newWords I want to replace oldWords with newWords in the string I already try to do it with for loop but it return the string with only the last word replaced.
Code:

```js
let myStr = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sapien magna.",
    old_Words = ["Lorem", "ipsum"],
    new_Words = ["word1", "word2"];
    
for (let i = 0; i < old_Words.length; i++) {
  var newStr = myStr.replace(old_Words[i], new_Words[i]);
}

console.log(newStr);
```

output should be:

```
"word1 word2 dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sapien magna."
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with `let newStr = myStr;` before the loop, then do `newStr = newStr.replace(...)` inside the loop:

```js
let myStr = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sapien magna.",
    old_Words = ["Lorem","ipsum"],
    new_Words = ["word1","word2"],
    newStr = myStr;

for (let i = 0; i < old_Words.length; i++){
  newStr = newStr.replace(old_Words[i], new_Words[i]);
}
console.log(newStr);
```

Comment: Note:  put Lorem again in your myStr..  It won't replace.

Comment: @Keith yes I want to replace it for the first time only>

Answer (score 2):

You can replace all the occurrences of old words with new words as follows:

**NOTE:**
This can replace multiple occurrences of words as well.

```
let myStr = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor Fusce sapien magna.",
    old_Words = ["Lorem","ipsum"],
    new_Words = ["word1","word2"];
    
old_Words.forEach((oldWord, idx) => {
  myStr = myStr.replace(RegExp(oldWord, 'g'), new_Words[idx])
});

console.log(myStr)
```

```js
let myStr = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem Fusce ipsum sapien magna.",
    old_Words = ["Lorem","ipsum"],
    new_Words = ["word1","word2"];
    
old_Words.forEach((oldWord, idx) => {
  myStr = myStr.replace(RegExp(oldWord, 'g'), new_Words[idx])
});

console.log(myStr)
```